I am having problem with my logistic regression model
My model accuracy is pretty bad. This data is taken from https://archive.ics.uci.edu/dataset/15/breast+cancer+wisconsin+original which shows logistics regression model accuracy of 96%, so really the problem is in my model. I have build the following model:
# Importing dataset 
tumor_study <- read.csv("breast-cancer-wisconsin.data", header = FALSE, na.strings = "NA")

# Adding column names
features <- c("id_number", "ClumpThickness", "Uniformity_CellSize",
              "Uniformity_CellShape", "MarginalAdhesion",
              "SingleEpithelial_CellSize", "BareNuclei", "Bland_Chromatin",
              "Normal_Nucleoli", "Mitoses", "Class")

colnames(tumor_study) <- features 

# Cleaning data
# Remove the 1st column (id_number)
tumor_study <- tumor_study[,-1]

# Convert "?" to NA in BareNuclei column and then to numeric
tumor_study$BareNuclei[tumor_study$BareNuclei == "?"] <- NA
tumor_study$BareNuclei <- as.numeric(tumor_study$BareNuclei)

# Remove rows with missing values in BareNuclei
tumor_study <- tumor_study[!is.na(tumor_study$BareNuclei),]

# Convert Class to a factor
tumor_study$Class <- factor(tumor_study$Class, levels = c(2, 4), labels = c("Benign", "Malignant"))

# Splitting the dataset into training and test sets
library(caTools)
set.seed(123)
split <- sample.split(tumor_study$Class, SplitRatio = 0.8)
training_set <- tumor_study[split == TRUE,]
test_set <- tumor_study[split == FALSE,]

# Applying feature scaling
training_set[, 1:9] <- scale(training_set[, 1:9])
test_set[, 1:9] <- scale(test_set[, 1:9])

# Building the logistic regression model
classifier <- glm(formula = Class ~ ., family = binomial, data = training_set)

# Predicting probabilities for the training set
prob_y_train <- predict(classifier, type = 'response', newdata = training_set[,-10])
predicted_y_training <- ifelse(prob_y_train >= 0.5, "Benign", "Malignant")

# prediction using test_set
prob_y_test <- predict(classifier, type = 'response', newdata = test_set[,-10])
predicted_y_test <- ifelse(prob_y_test >= 0.5, "Benign", "Malignant")

# Checking the accuracy with confusion matrix
cm_test <- table(test_set[,10], predicted_y_test)
print(cm_test)

But my accuracy is close to 2%.
How can I figure out the problem in my model?

You shouldn't scale training and test set independently. Scale the training set and apply the same scaling to the test set.

You're predicting "Malignant", not "Benign", since the outcome is a factor with 2 levels and the R glm function predicts the second level when running logistic regression.
levels(training_set$Class)
[1] "Benign"    "Malignant"

Just switch "Benign" with "Malignant" for your two ifelse commands and you'll get a much better accuracy.
predicted_y_training <- ifelse(prob_y_train >= 0.5, "Malignant", "Benign")
predicted_y_test <- ifelse(prob_y_test >= 0.5, "Malignant", "Benign")
...

print(cm_test)
           predicted_y_test
            Benign Malignant
  Benign        86         3
  Malignant      2        46


I learned something new. Thank you

@jojo If this answers your question, consider accepting it. ;)
